# MVC ajax Form post deserizile issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to post a form of formenctype="multipart/form-data" with a Model and file(HttpPostedFileWrapper) and when getting the response the whole page is returned rather than just the updated partial view.

Form:

```
  <textarea rows="3" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Write a reply...">        </textarea>

 <button id="btnNewComment" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Send</button>

<label class="control-label">Attach a file:</label>
<input type="file" name="postedFile" id="postedFile">

</form>
<div id="list">@Html.Partial("View", Model)</div>
<script>
$(function () {
        var options = {
            target: '#list',
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
            success: showResponse,  // post-submit callback
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err)
            },

        };
        // bind to the form's submit event 
        $('#myForm').submit(function () {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

            return false;
        });
    });

    // pre-submit callback 
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var queryString = $.param(formData);

        alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString);

        return true;
    }

    // post-submit callback 
    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {

        alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText +
            '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
    }
```

I should also mention I am using jQuery Form Plugin any advise would be appreciated.

```
    //
    // POST: /Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Model thread, HttpPostedFileWrapper postedFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var model = (Class)Shared.SelectedConversation;

                model.Create(thread, postedFile);

                return View("View", model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                while (ex.InnerException != null)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the server code?

Comment: I have updated to include these details now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating part of view after submitting a post using jquery ajax in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866213/updating-part-of-view-after-submitting-a-post-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)